# Eloquent not recognizing table names

Tags: laravel

I have the following in my Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('plan_submissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        //This is the advisor_id for the advisor who created the Plan Submission
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('advisor_id')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('advisor_id')->references('id')->on('advisors');
```

I have the following in my Plan Submission Model:

```
    public function advisor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Advisor::class);
}
```

The primary key on my Advisor Model is 'id'.

I have the following within and If/Else statement in my Controller:

```
        elseif (request('advisor_last_name')) {
        PlanSubmission::whereHas('advisor', function ($query) {
            $query->where('last_name', request('advisor_last_name'))->paginate(25)->appends('advisor_last_name', request('advisor_last_name'));
        });
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'plan_submissions.advisor_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `advisors` where `plan_submissions`.`advisor_id` = `advisors`.`id` and `last_name` = bayne)
```

I cannot understand why this error message is appearing

Comment: why are you using `->appends('advisor_last_name', request('advisor_last_name')`?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your plan submission model

```
public function advisor() 
{
  $this->belongsTo('App\Advisor', 'advisor_id', id);
}
```